# Is it possible for Google to Index a site with login?

Tags: google-index, registration

I have a real estate site that we require the user to login after viewing 3 properties.  Is it possible for Google to index these property listings while still keeping that functionality in place?  What is the best way to handle this on the up and up with Google?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a great use-case for [First Click Free](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/09/first-click-free-update.html) - which would allow you to show the full content to Googlebot, while limiting the number of times a user can access content from there.

Comment: I have read a little about this but not exactly sure how it works.  I didn't realize until reading this article that it works for regular web search.  Everything i had been reading about it was geared directly towards news.  This is a very interesting idea!  Have you ever used it and had success outside of the news articles?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is something called submitting URL Parameters in google webmasters.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters

If you want the bot to read the contents inside a page that is shown after login, you can submit the url of the php or link that handles the login form along with parameters of login.

Hope that helps.

Comment: what do you mean by php ? Do I need to take the page address from cpanel ?

Comment: no. If your login form submits to `yoursite.com/login.php` with the parameters `username` and `password`, then you have to submit `yoursite.com/login.php` with the username and password parameters with values that are accepted by the server. I don't know how secure this is though. Always good to create a test or bot profile separately and provide the login parameters for that account.

Comment: Thanks @AtulBhatS.  I'm not sure I completely understand but will definitely try to look into this solution more.  Have you had success doing something like this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How do you find out of the 3 views? Cookies?

If so, whitelist crawlbot IP's to not get the cookies. Possible in .htaccess file

Comment: Would that be considered cloaking and potentially harm the site?